# Does chaining methods vs making temporary variables in Java impact memory allocation?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, heap-memory, allocation

In Java, if I'm performing multiple methods on an object, I can chain them, or I can make a temporary variable, like so

Chaining

```
    System.out.println( str.substring(0,4).substring(0,2));
```

Temp variable

```
    String tmp = str.substring(0,4);
    tmp = tmp.substring(0,2);
    System.out.println(tmp);
```

Obviously, the difference is negligible in this example, but could make an impact when you're doing this over thousands of strings/some other object.

My question is, is one of these more "efficient" in terms of not making extra object allocations or filling the heap (and thus making GC get called sooner)?

I tried to compare the bytecodes of the two in a loop over a couple strings, but it looks similar, sans for the last few lines. I don't understand all the bytecode calls, so I'm not sure if any of these have to do with allocating new objects.

```
Compiled from "TestNoTmp.java"
public class TestNoTmp {
  public TestNoTmp();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: iconst_4
       1: anewarray     #2                  // class java/lang/String
       4: dup
       5: iconst_0
       6: ldc           #3                  // String These
       8: aastore
       9: dup
      10: iconst_1
      11: ldc           #4                  // String Are__
      13: aastore
      14: dup
      15: iconst_2
      16: ldc           #5                  // String Some_
      18: aastore
      19: dup
      20: iconst_3
      21: ldc           #6                  // String Strings
      23: aastore
      24: astore_1
      25: aload_1
      26: astore_2
      27: aload_2
      28: arraylength
      29: istore_3
      30: iconst_0
      31: istore        4
      33: iload         4
      35: iload_3
      36: if_icmpge     69
      39: aload_2
      40: iload         4
      42: aaload
      43: astore        5
      45: getstatic     #7                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
      48: aload         5
      50: iconst_0
      51: iconst_4
      52: invokevirtual #8                  // Method java/lang/String.substring:(II)Ljava/lang/String;
      55: iconst_0
      56: iconst_2
      57: invokevirtual #8                  // Method java/lang/String.substring:(II)Ljava/lang/String;
      60: invokevirtual #9                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
      63: iinc          4, 1
      66: goto          33
      69: return
}

public class TestTmp {
  public TestTmp();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: iconst_4
       1: anewarray     #2                  // class java/lang/String
       4: dup
       5: iconst_0
       6: ldc           #3                  // String These
       8: aastore
       9: dup
      10: iconst_1
      11: ldc           #4                  // String Are__
      13: aastore
      14: dup
      15: iconst_2
      16: ldc           #5                  // String Some_
      18: aastore
      19: dup
      20: iconst_3
      21: ldc           #6                  // String Strings
      23: aastore
      24: astore_1
      25: aload_1
      26: astore_2
      27: aload_2
      28: arraylength
      29: istore_3
      30: iconst_0
      31: istore        4
      33: iload         4
      35: iload_3
      36: if_icmpge     77
      39: aload_2
      40: iload         4
      42: aaload
      43: astore        5
      45: aload         5
      47: iconst_0
      48: iconst_4
      49: invokevirtual #7                  // Method java/lang/String.substring:(II)Ljava/lang/String;
      52: astore        6
      54: aload         6
      56: iconst_0
      57: iconst_2
      58: invokevirtual #7                  // Method java/lang/String.substring:(II)Ljava/lang/String;
      61: astore        6
      63: getstatic     #8                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
      66: aload         6
      68: invokevirtual #9                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
      71: iinc          4, 1
      74: goto          33
      77: return
}
```

Comment: Well there's your answer. While `javac` doesn't do much optimization, these kinds of minor things have no effect on the resulting bytecode. Also, you might want to concentrate on real performance bottlenecks. This wouldn't be one, even if the temp variable did affect the bytecode.

Comment: The bytecode varies slightly though, so I wasn't sure if that made an impact, or if my assumption was right (I could have written my example in a way that doesn't make a difference)

Comment: It does not make a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, you're working with Strings, which are immutable.  In your code:

```
str.substring(0,4).substring(0,2)
```

the first call to substring must generate a new String object because str cannot be modified.  Similarly, the second call to substring on that new String object will create another new String object.

The difference in bytecodes is simply a result of the order in which the compiler calls methods.  In the TestTmp case, all the string manipulation occurs before the call to PrintStream.  For TestNoTmp, the String calls happen within the PrintStream call, which is very logical when you look at the code.

To answer your question, this will make no difference in terms of object allocation and therefore GC impact.