# Java method param: cached result vs direct call

Tags: java, methods

I had hard time describing what I mean exactly in the topic so let's stick to the example.

Given a hypothetical set of methods

```
Object firstObject();
Object secondObject();
void myMethod(Object o1, Object o2);
```

**Is there a any difference between the following pieces of code, other than *style*?**

```
// Code 1.
myMethod(firstObject(), secondObject());
```

```
// Code 2.
Object o1 = firstObject();
Object o2 = secondObject();
myMethod(o1,o2);
```

I am asking mostly due to the fact that I came across some really long lines of code due to `Code 1.` type of style and I am wondering if there are really any benefits of having it written like that.

Comment: I think the only benefit of doing it code1-like is that you don't need to assign `firstObject()` and `secondObject()` to anything. So it's up to you as it depends on whether or not you might need `o1` and `o2` after having called `myMethod`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are asking if there is any overhead to refactoring a method call result to a variable then answer is no.
One significant pro for option 1 is better readability and ability to easily use a debugger.

Here's an example of the same question in a bit more in depth manner: [Does chaining methods vs making temporary variables in Java impact memory allocation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45764204/does-chaining-methods-vs-making-temporary-variables-in-java-impact-memory-alloca)

Important part is:

> To answer your question, this will make no difference in terms of object allocation and therefore GC impact.